# Grabbing the jQuery Promtbox value and storing into a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

For some reason, I am unable to set the value of "myvar" once the jQuery Prompt box is called. The code for this file is here: http://pastebin.com/40hD3Q8e

How can the code below be modified such that I am able to set the myvar value of the prompt box text.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>


        <style type="text/css">

            /* Custom dialog styles */
            #popup_container.style_1 {
                font-family: Georgia, serif;
                color: #A4C6E2;
                background: #005294;
                border-color: #113F66;
            }

            #popup_container.style_1 #popup_title {
                color: #FFF;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-align: left;
                background: #76A5CC;
                border: solid 1px #005294;
                padding-left: 1em;
            }

            #popup_container.style_1 #popup_content {
                background: none;
            }

            #popup_container.style_1 #popup_message {
                padding-left: 0em;
            }

            #popup_container.style_1 INPUT[type='button'] {
                border: outset 2px #76A5CC;
                color: #A4C6E2;
                background: #3778AE;
            }

        </style>

        <!-- Core files -->
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
var myvar
    alert("working")

    jPrompt('Type something:', 'Prefilled value', 'Prompt Dialog', function(r) {
    //if( r ) { alert('You entered ' + r) }
    myvar = r
    });

    alert(myvar)
}

</script>

    </head>

    <body>

                <input id="alert_button" type="button" value="Show Alert" />

                <input id="confirm_button" type="button" value="Show Confirm" />

                <input id="prompt_button" type="button" value="Show Prompt" />

                <input id="alert_button_with_html" type="button" value="Show Alert" />

                <input id="style_1" class="alert_style_example" type="button" value="Style 1" />

                <br>

                <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="testthis"/>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working because , your `alert(myvar);` is executed before the `jPropmt()`'s callback, like:

```
jPrompt('Type something:', 'Prefilled value', 'Prompt Dialog', function(r) {
    //if( r ) { alert('You entered ' + r) }
    myvar = r;
});
```

`alert(myvar);` //this gets executed before `jPrompt()`'s callback, so you could create a hidden field in you html with some id, say `prompt_val`, and then do:

```
jPrompt('Type something:', 'Prefilled value', 'Prompt Dialog', function(r) {
    if( r ) { 
        $("#prompt_val").val(r);
    }
});
```

and get the value from hidden field